# Javascript Clear all script. High I/O usage

Tags: javascript, performance

Using this script

```
function clearChildren(element) {
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
//for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
var e = element.childNodes[i];
if (e.tagName) switch (e.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
case 'input':
switch (e.type) {
case "radio":
case "checkbox": e.checked = false; break;
case "button":
case "submit":
case "image": break;
default: e.value = ''; break;
}
break;
case 'textarea': e.value = ''; break;
case 'select': e.selectedIndex = -1; break;
default: clearChildren(e);
}
}
}
```

On CPanel see high I/O usage. `element.childNodes.length` is 30 and for each row there are ~20 columns.

Is it possible to improve the script to reduce I/O usage? Or it is because of so many columns/rows?

Removed `case "radio":` and other unnecessary, but I/O usage is the same.

Please advice what to do

Comment: JavaScript is executed on the client, not the server, so cPanel wouldn't have any idea what's going on.

Comment: hmmm, yes, but I checked. When removed the script, I/O reduced. Also tested with `dunaTrace AJAX Edition` and see duration 3635,12 ms. In any case there is problem with the script. And need to change something

Comment: I don't see any AJAX at all in your code above.

Comment: No `Ajax`. It is software name https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/AJAX/dynaTrace+AJAX+Edition+Community+Home Checks `javascript`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with your function? are you trying to clear the form?

Comment: Have form with multiple columns and rows. For each row has own `Clear` button and at the end of all rows is `Clear all` button. If click on `Clear`, then clears only particular row. If click on `Clear All`, then clear all form. This is what the script do